# What is the name for this bug-finding technique and do programs exist to automate it?

Tags: debugging, automation

Let's say I have some giant program `P` which I know has a bug in it: when I run it with argument `A` it prints the ugly error message `E`. In shell notation, this happens:

```
$ ./P A
E
$
```

Now I don't have any idea what causes the bug, but it appears to be deterministic. My approach to finding the bug is to "isolate" it. I "reduce" the program `P` to the "smallest" version that still generates the error `E` given the argument `A`. By "reduce", I mean I will chop out parts of the program and manually inline functions, testing at every stage that `P A --> E` and not a success response or some other error message. Once I can't reduce it any more, I have a small program that probably gets to the core of the issue.

This process is fairly mechanical: it doesn't require much "insight" on my part. It feels like it could be done automatically: there could be some program `X` which, given `P`, `A`, and `E`, spits out the smallest program `P'` such that `P` reduces to `P'` and `P' A --> E`.

So, does this strategy have a name, and has it been automated in any sense for any programming language?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "smallest program"; the smallest such program is `printf("E\n");`...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth true, which is why I included the restriction that `P` reduces to `P'`, according to my definition of "reduction".

Comment: @OliCharlesworth to clarify: you're right that if `P` itself prints `E`, then it could "reduce" to `printf("E")`; however I'm thinking of cases where `E` is, say, a stacktrace, or an exception from some external library.

Comment: This might not be as easy to automate as you think: just deleting random lines of a properly structured program won't result in a simpler version of the same program, but something completely different, which probably won't work at all.

Comment: @IMSoP I'm not sure what you mean by "won't work" in this context since we're dealing with a non-working program from the outset. The perspective I'm suggesting is to divide programs into those that generate E and those that don't; the latter class includes correct programs, non-compiling programs, programs with new features, random text, etc.

Comment: My thought was that you have a large search space (all programs whose code exists within P) and defining a good algorithm for navigating that search space is far from trivial for most programming languages. Naively chopping up the text - even if you respected block boundaries - will lead to many dead ends which don't resemble P in any meaningful way; some may however produce E by coincidence, thus appearing to be P'.

Comment: It may be that the shortest P' findable by such methods would not eliminate much code, since a more succinct test case (effectively, a Unit Test for the bug) would require complex transforms (e.g. trying a series of possible inputs to a function without the rest of the program needing to generate them) which are easier to do in your head than train an AI for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Finally stumbled over something that answers my question!](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8089359) Apparently, this technique is known as "reduction" or "minimization". See:

- [CReduce](http://embed.cs.utah.edu/creduce/), which performs a generalized version of the reduction that I described, specifically for C programs.
- [Delta](http://delta.tigris.org/), a very similar program.
- [DustMite](https://github.com/CyberShadow/DustMite/wiki), another similar program, for minimizing D programs.
- [Delta debugging](https://www.st.cs.uni-saarland.de/dd/), a page which describes the general process.
- [A Guide to Testcase Reduction](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/A_guide_to_testcase_reduction) on the GCC wiki.